# Referencing a variable outside php tag

Tags: php, html

I have a form set up like this

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

<? php

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'nabeel', 'nab33l', 'rabbi');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM poetry WHERE id = ".$id.";"

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $Id = $rows[Id];
    $title = $rows[title];
    $author= $rows[author];
    $entry= $rows[entry];

        <form method="post" action="../">

            <label>ID</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="" name="Id" value='$Id'><br>

            <label>TITLE</label><br>
            <input type="text" id ="" name= "title" value=$title><br>

            <label>Author</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="" name= "author" value=$author><br>

            <label>Entry</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="" name= "entry" value=$entry><br>

            <label>Time & Date</label><br>
            <input type="datetime-local" id="" name= "timeanddate" value=$timeanddate ><br>

            <input type= 'hidden' name='form_submitted', value='1'>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ><br>
?>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Now I cannot seem to call the variables declared in php tag any where else. I could move the form inside the php tag but I wanted to know if there was some proper way to achieve this.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. For one thing, you're not echoing anything and what you posted doesn't hold water.

Comment: PHP only evaluates stuff in `<?php ?>` tags. It doesn’t work outside of that because anything outside isn’t PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `<?php echo $variable ?>` around your variable. (and you may declare it globally)

If the variable is user input you have a perfect XSS Vector by the way.